# How do I update path npx version?

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, npx

When I run `npx --version`, it returns me v6.x.x

But after I do `npm install -g npx`, `yarn global add npx`, and it shows successful download of npx v10, running `npx --version` still returns me v6.x.x

Running where npx gives me:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx
C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx.cmd
C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx
C:\Users\Samson\AppData\Roaming\npm\npx.cmd
```

Comment: Can you please enter this command. npm install -g npx

Comment: I already tried that as mentioned in the question

Comment: this solution has been worked for me
  1- sudo npm uninstall -g npx
   2- sudo  npm install  -g npx
for windows use terminal as administrator

Comment: nope didn't work for me either

Answer (score 15):

Ran into the same issue, this is what worked for me:

1. Delete each one of the files listed in the output of `where npx`, for example `del "C:\Program Files\nodejs\npx"`
2. Run `npm uninstall -g npx`
3. Run `npm install -g npx@10.2.2` (or whatever version you want to install)

After doing these steps, when I run `npx --version` I see the correct one, and the issue that required me to upgrade npx is fixed.

Comment: This could be related to a more broad issue with the way Windows installs node/npm. 
 Windows defaults to the version of NPM installed in the nodeJS directory in program files rather than the one installed by npm install -g  npm.  It seems likely that this could also be true for NPX.  https://docs.npmjs.com/try-the-latest-stable-version-of-npm